# how can I get the desired output?

Tags: c

I tried using the for loop for the test cases as I thought that would bring the desired output but it didn't

```
int main() 
{
  int num, temp, digit, sum = 0;
  int test,i;
  scanf("%d",&test);
  for(i=1;i<=test;i++)
   {
     printf("\n");
     scanf("%d", &num);
     temp = num;
     while (num != 0)
    {
      digit = num % 10;
      sum  = sum + digit;
      num /= 10;
    }
      printf("%d",sum);
   }
   return 0; 
}
```

Expected results- 2 123 456
           Output- 6 15

Obtained Results- 2 123 456
           Output- 6 21

The first  output is correct but at the second print it is summing up    the first result with the second line which I don't want.

Comment: Is this the code you tested?  The code in the question will never complete since the I variable never changes in the for loop.

Comment: Sorry,got ommitted while formatting,I hope now it's correct

Answer (score 0):

You never clear sum after processing 123.  You are calculating the correct sum (15) but it is being added to the sum from the previous step (6).  To fix the problem clear sum inside the for loop.

```
for(i=1;i<=test;i++)
   {
     sum = 0;
     printf("\n");
```